# Hibernate - order of parameters in insert/update generated statements when using Annotations

Tags: hibernate, insert, annotations

I'd like to ask about the order of parameters Hibernate uses in it's automatically generated insert/update statements.

Let me quote Hibernate reference first:

> The order of the positional parameters are currently vital, as they must be in the same sequence as Hibernate expects them.
>
> You can see the expected order by enabling debug logging for the
> org.hibernate.persister.entity level. With this level enabled
> Hibernate will print out the static SQL that is used to create,
> update, delete etc. entities. (To see the expected sequence, remember
> to not include your custom SQL in the mapping files as that will
> override the Hibernate generated static sql.)

I found out (by doing some quick testing) that the order of parameters when you use XML mappings is exactly the same as the order of properties in the XML file.

Example:

```
<many-to-one name="rezerwacja" class="model_mapowanie_xml.Trezerwacja" fetch="select">
    <column name="IdRezerwacja" not-null="true" />
</many-to-one>
<property name="kwota" type="big_decimal">
    <column name="Kwota" scale="4" not-null="true" />
</property>
<property name="data" type="timestamp">
    <column name="Data" length="19" not-null="true" />
</property>
```

generates *insert into HotelDB.TPlatnosc (IdRezerwacja, Kwota, Data)*.

When you switch positions of Kwota and Data in the xml, insert would be *insert into HotelDB.TPlatnosc (IdRezerwacja, Data, Kwota)*. That's for XML.

**My question is: can I somehow predict what order to expect when using Annotations?**